# Oracle Forms and Reports 11g - Library Files

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms, oracle-ebs

am working in a oracle apps re-implementation project 
From oracle ebs 11i to R12.2.5

My Job is to do the retrofitting changes of existing 6i forms and reports to 11g forms.Since its a new instance am not able to find the library files for forms 11g. Can some one help me with these setups (Path + where I can get the files)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry ..  The answer depends on each enterprise set up.

I found the library files in our $AU_TOP path

and I kept inside my forms 11g .

Yet to test this .. but this is the solution.

Comment: btw Forms  builder 11g will not work in R12.2- we need to use 10g forms builder